# Miss behaving Expressions window and no Display View window in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I was doing debugging with having a lots of expressions in Expressions Window. Then I mistakenly dragged Values column of Expressions window in eclipse and suddenly I was not able see any of Name and Value columns along with any of my expressions in expression window.

This is how it looks:
[image]

Also, I am not finding [Display View window](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdisplay%2Fref-display_view.htm) in eclipse:

[image]

I tried to reset the perspective and also restart the eclipse. However, nothing changed. What is happening with me?

I am running

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **view menu** (the triangle top right) **of the *Expressions* view** you can choose which columns to show: ***Layout > Select Columns...***

[image]

By selecting other columns here, the column width is reset (in case a column width was accidentally set to 0). By default, the *Name* and the *Value* columns are shown.

In Eclipse Photon (4.8) the [***Display* view** has been **renamed to *Debug Shell***](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php#debug-shell).

Comment: super thanks...I didnt change which columns to show in expressions window and Name and Value columns already had tick in front of them. I deselected all and clicked ok. Then I re-selected them and clicked ok. And they re appeared!!! :\